# SQL Modifying Data based on value within same ID

Tags: sql

I want to update my table with 'Update' if one of the row with the same ID_AWB have 'Update'.  Below is the current table looks like.

```
ID | ID_AWB | Piece Code | Action
1     12       ABC123      Release
2     12       ABC456      Update
3     13       A123        Update
4     13       A456        Release
5     13       A226        Release
6     14       XJ124       Release
7     14       XJ125       Release
```

Should be:

```
ID | ID_AWB | Piece Code | Action
1     12       ABC123      Update (As 1 row with ID_AWB=12 have Update)
2     12       ABC456      Update
3     13       A123        Update
4     13       A456        Update (As 1 row with ID_AWB=13 have Update)
5     13       A226        Update (As 1 row with ID_AWB=13 have Update)
6     14       XJ124       Release
7     14       XJ125       Release
```

I have the idea to do it using If condition, where first we select all the row which have the same id_awb. Then check if 1 of the row have 'Update'. If have 'Update', then Action=Update. Below is my current progress and stuck for a long time. If have any better solution with better speed, please suggest me.

```
    Update cems.WGT_Main
    set [Action] = ( 
                    Select t.ID_AWB, t.Action from cems.WGT_Main t
                    where t.ID_AWB=WGT_Main.ID_AWB
                    )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```
UPDATE cems.WGT_Main t1
SET [Action] = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cems.WGT_Main t2
                                 WHERE t2.ID_AWB = t1.ID_AWB AND t2.[Action] = 'Update')
                    THEN 'Update' ELSE [Action] END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This method run faster than my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `case` for this.  I would filter in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE cems.WGT_Main m
    SET [Action] = 'Update'
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM cems.WGT_Main m2
                  WHERE m.ID_AWB = m.ID_AWB AND m.[Action] = 'Update'
                 ) AND
          [Action] <> 'Update';
```

This should be faster than the `CASE` version, because fewer rows are being updated.